# How to limit the keys of an object to the strings of an array in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an array of valid key names

```
const validKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I create an object type that accepts only these keys? This doesn't work:

```
interface MyObject {
  [key in validKeys]: number // for example
}
```

Comment: is validKeys array static or  dynamically created ?

Comment: do you need to access the object with an index? e.g `myObject['a']`

Comment: @OnurArı Let's say it's static and I will have to access the object as `myObj.a`

Comment: @nachocab Assuming it's static and you don't need to access it with an index, you can just declare `interface MyObject { a: number; b: number; c: number }` if the keys are optional `interface MyObject { a?: number; b?: number; c?: number } .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`const`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) assertion (added in typescript 3.4) in order to preserve literal types of array items:

```
const validKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type Keys = (typeof validKeys)[number]; // "a" | "b" | "c"

type MyObject = { [key in Keys]: number } // { a: number; b: number; c: number; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20validKeys%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%5D%20as%20const%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Keys%20%3D%20(typeof%20validKeys)%5Bnumber%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MyObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Keys%5D%3A%20number%20%7D)

If you use an older typescript version (>=3.0), you can add small utility function which will convert parameters to tuple of literals:

```
const tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T): T => args;
const validKeys = tuple('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `validKeys` are static you can create a type for it. And then from that type, you can set type for object keys.
You can do something like:

```
type ValidKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type MyObject = {
    [key in ValidKeys]?: number //You can remove ? if all the keys are mandatory
}

const validKeys: ValidKeys[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const obj: MyObject = {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
}
```

> The keys of object `obj` can only be one of ValidKeys.